# Run javascript code after angularjs route loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous

I need to show an alert after a route has been loaded by angularjs. The piece of code to show the alert is in the view loaded asynchronously by angularjs:

```
<script>
alert('test');
</script>
```

Once the view has loaded, I expect this to be run, but it does not. I know I can broadcast and tell it to run afterwards etc, but I need a more generic solution.

Comment: I have seen the same question up here http://www.cybertechquestions.com/run-javascript-code-after-angularjs-route-loaded_333930.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about route changes based upon `ngRoute` internal to an angular SPA

Inject $route into your controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $route){});
```

and in your controller you subscribe to the event of the route changing:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    alert('test'); // <-- alert from the question
});
```

Comment: how can I do this on a specific route?

Comment: @AhmedNassar this is possible, but a separate question should be created  so that others that have that issue can find it and find it useful. You can post a link to your question here and I will take a look at it then.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more option to run javascript function use `ngInit`

```
<div ng-init="initialize()"></div>
```

call the function which is inside the controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.initialize = function () {
        alert("Page loading just completed");
    }
});
```