# Select box is not displaying options in angular and material in source it showing up when i inspect element

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col m7 s12">
        <label>Venue</label>
            <input ng-model="event.venue" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m5 s12">
        <select ng-model="event.cordinator" ng-options="cordinator._id as cordinator.name for cordinator in cordinators" class="validate">

       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image of a bigger section:

[image]

Comment: Insufficient information . Can you show the CSS being applied to select?

Comment: I included the image link as a picture and clarified the Title a little bit. The title needs further improvement, as does the text which needs a more thorough explanation of the problem.

Comment: there is not custom css applied to it but i am using materialcss.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker or fiddle link of your full code.

Answer (score 0):

we also need to initialize it either by material select or using jquery

```
$("#cordinator").select2({
    placeholder: "Select the events",
    allowClear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but anyone landing on this page in future may find it helpfull. Material select box needs to be initialised using jquery onload for it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
});
```

If you are binding a page to ng-view using ngRoute. The onload option may not work, then you need to inject $route to controller and do this

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097900/2206350)